# ExecuteReader throws Incorrect Syntax near "="

Tags: c#, sql

while running this code i am getting an error showing incorrect syntax near "=", highlighting the  "SqlDataReader drs = cmd.ExecuteReader();"
Really surprising and got stuck with this now... need help.!!!

```
public void nextCourseDisplay(string crscode)
{
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        string count = string.Empty;
        cmd.Connection = CPublic.Comm_con;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CID",crscode);
        cmd.CommandText = "select RECNO from COURSEMASTER" + CPublic.g_firmcode + "where CID = @CID";
        SqlDataReader drs = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (drs.HasRows)
        {
            if (drs.Read())
            {
                count = drs.GetString(0);
            }
            drs.Close();
        }
}
```

Comment: You might be lacking spaces in your SQL query (e.g. just after `COURSEMASTER` and before `where`).

Comment: Boy, I hope the value of `CPublic.g_firmcode` is never `"; DELETE FROM COURSEMASTER; --"`.

Comment: Sniped by @stellarchariot, this would cause issues.

Comment: Can you explain the difference between CID and crscode? Seems like a pointless way to introduce confusion.

Comment: You should always use [_parameterized queries_](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html). This kind of queries are open for [_SQL Injection_](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add an extra space to your SQL-statement before `where`:

```
"select RECNO from COURSEMASTER" + CPublic.g_firmcode + " where CID = @CID"
                                                         ^
```

If you do this the value of `CPublic.g_firmcode` is seperated from `where`. Otherwise `where` is part of your table name.

Comment: Probably just after g_firmcode, assuming the tables are COURSEMASTER1, COURSEMASTER2 etc. (Seems like a horrible design to me, admittedly.)

Comment: @Martin Mulder, now the error changed and am on. Thank's...

Comment: @Nik: You're welcome. Since you're new here, please don't forget to mark the answer accepted which helped most in solving the problem. See also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

What value is crscode? If it is an empty string or null I guess the sql interpreter will not work and give you the error you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

Check your sql statement, and try to print  cmd.CommandText  before you execute it!